# Develop Application using extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

Recently my company asked me to gather knowledge in EXTJS. I have seen a lot of examples from  Sencha

But, when I want to develop applications using extjs what should i do? Now I want to dive into building application using ExtJS. Please give me some link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's definitely a bit of a learning curve with Ext, but the best place to start really is their MVC application tutorial and just reading the application documentation:

- Tutorials:

  - [Ext MVC Intro](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/application_architecture%5d)
  - [App Architecture pt 1](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/mvc_pt1)
  - [App Architecture pt 2](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/mvc_pt2)
  - [App Architecture pt 3](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/guide/mvc_pt3)
- Documentation:

  - [App documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.app.Application)

In addition, I would make sure to get an understanding of how the event system works in extjs as it is the core of how wiring the components together works.  Have a look at the [base observable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable) class to get some detailed information - all the components that can fire events inherit this class.  Generally speaking, the documentation is your friend in Ext though.

One thing I did while learning ext was read over Jay Garcia's book [ExtJS In Action](http://www.manning.com/garcia/).  By no means will it teach you everything you need to know, but it gives a good overview of what Ext is capable of and some common usage patterns.